# Is wp-app.php or wp-apps.php needed for Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, hacked

A few Wordpress blogs I overlook have suddenly generated 3 PHP files in their top folder: wp-app.php, wp-apps.php, and wp-register.php, not of which existed before. Checking their contents against a few Google searches suggests I have been infiltrated by a common Wordpress exploit.

Since they keep regenerating, I thought about blanking them and setting file permissions to readonly or less. But if they're needed by WP I don't want to compromise site functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if they're needed by WP I don't want to compromise site functions.

[Those are not Core files.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src)

It is possible that a plugin has added the files legitimately but the behavior described suggests a hack. Recovering from hacks is off-topic here though, as it usually requires hands-on server access and is often very localized.

Answer (score 1):

Google the file names like `wp-apps.php` and you'll find that they can be hacking files; previous hacks used files of the same name: http://www.google.com/search?&q=wp-apps.php

"Since they keep regenerating,..."  that means they are being uploaded each time or being recreated with another script.

Download a new archive of WordPress and you'll see the standard files and folders and/or see s_ha_dum's link to https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that is it just an old (old) version of Wordpress which did have a file at the root level called wp-app.php. See below the comment from the header of the file.

```
wp-app.php - Atom Publishing Protocol support for WordPress
```

So this is not always a sign of a hack. It may just be a sign that you badly need to upgrade Wordpress (and delete older files left behind from previous versions).